# what are the possible permutations of 8 digits

Tags: python, permutation

I need to know what are the possible permutations of 8 digits following the rules of my python code:

```
import itertools
import time
import string

numbers = set(range(10))
letters = set(string.ascii_letters)
mylist=[]
start=time.time()

comb = ([x for x in itertools.combinations([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'], 8)
       if set(x) & letters and set(x) & numbers])

f=open("data.txt","w")
f.write("%s" % comb)
f.close()

end=time.time()
diff=end-start

print ("Se obtuvieron {} combinaciones.".format(len(comb)))
print ("En un tiempo total de:",diff,"segundos")
```

Comment: combinations or permutations?  One is in the code and one is your tag, but they are not the same thing.

Comment: @MarkTolonen sorry, they are actually permutations and is 8 digits, excuse my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of them.  To be clear:

- Combinations of 123 for 2 digits are 12, 13, 23.
- Permutations of 123 for 2 digits are 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32.

Combinations is a smaller number because order doesn't matter.  Your code looks like you require at least one number or letter in your 8-digit combination, so you need the sum of:

- Combinations of 1 digit times combinations of 7 letters.
- Combinations of 2 digits times combinations of 6 letters.
  etc...
- Combinations of 7 digits times combinations of 1 letter.

Permutations should be 62 letters/numbers taken 8 at a time, minus the all-letter permutations of 52 letters taken 8 at a time, minus the all-number permutations of 10 numbers taken 8 at a time.

```
from math import factorial as f

def P(n,k):
    return f(n)//f(n-k)

def C(n,k):
    return f(n)//f(n-k)//f(k)

letters = 52
numbers = 10
length = 8
combinations = sum(C(numbers,i) * C(letters,length-i) for i in range(1,length))
print('Combinations: {:20,}'.format(combinations))

permutations = P(letters+numbers,length) - P(letters,length) - P(numbers,length)
print('Permutations: {:20,}'.format(permutations))
```

Output:

```
Combinations:        2,628,560,350
Permutations:  105,983,553,312,000
```

Trying to generate all those combinations or permutations in an in-memory list as your code is doing is not a good idea.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but you're considering that my code does not store the following permutations? ABCEFGTH or 12345678 or AAAAAAAA etc, etc ..

Comment: AAAAAAAA is not a permutation. If you allow repeats, that is a Cartesian product and there are even more of them.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I don't think you are asking the right question. You say permutation, but your code uses combinations, those are different things.

I will not give you the complete answer, because it would take forever to compute that. To put it in perspective just how big this number is. The permutation of 8 numbers from 0~9 is: **1.814.400**

Starting with: (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), ending in (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2)

You can demonstrate how many permutation of 8 there's in all the ASCII letters with the numbers from 0~9 using this:

```
mylist = range(10)
mylist.extend(ascii_letters)
i = 0
for n in permutations(mylist,8):
    i += 1
```

But this will take VERY LONG, just to show how big this number is:

I ran it for a couple of minutes and it was over 1.500.000.000.( 1.5 billion )

Also, your code doesn't make much sense. Why do you need to calculate such big number? Why do you need to write it to a file(it will probably take forever/run out memory and/or space). Try elaborating what you want.

Comment: I want to convert md5 but given that is too long to think not I will continue with the program :( thank you very much anyway file.